# Using Kudan without paid Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, kudan

I'm a beginner with kudan and iOS development and I'm trying to get the example provided on kudan.eu running in Xcode. I don't have a paid Apple Developer account, I'm using the free 7 day provisioning profiles and the developer API-Keys from kudan. This means I am using the bundle identifier.

```
eu.kudan.ar
```

But I can't find where I can get a "wildcard provisioning profile" to use this bundle identifier, neither in Xcode or in https://developer.apple.com . Is it even possible to use kudan with the free provisioning profiles?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with unity?

Comment: A paid Apple developer account is not longer needed to build and test apps on a device. You'll only need a paid account once you want to distribute an app via Test Flight or through the App Store. See https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: I'm aware of that. I have already used the free 7 day provisioning profiles, but I need a "wildcard provisioning profile" so that I can share the bundle identifier which is necessary to use kudan with the free API-Keys.

Comment: Well, you need a wildcard profile to use it, and if you can't get one through automatic provisioning or by using a free 7-day trial, then yeah, you'll probably have to join Apple's developer program.